# How do you do a groupby and sum on a pandas Series with multi-level indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series object called `busyness` that was created in the following manner from DataFrames:

```
entries = last.ENTRIES - first.ENTRIES
exits   = last.EXITS   - first.EXITS
busyness = entries + exits
```

where `last` and `first` are dataframes with a column for ENTRIES. Here is what `busyness` looks like:

```
ipdb> type(busyness)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

ipdb> busyness.head(20)
CA    UNIT  SCP       STATION
A002  R051  02-00-00  59 ST         2468
            02-00-01  59 ST         1764
            02-03-00  59 ST         3063
            02-03-01  59 ST         3952
            02-03-02  59 ST         3576
            02-03-03  59 ST         3168
            02-03-04  59 ST         2563
            02-03-05  59 ST         2948
            02-03-06  59 ST         2350
            02-05-00  59 ST            0
            02-05-01  59 ST            0
            02-06-00  59 ST         2503
A006  R079  00-00-00  5 AV/59 ST    4321
            00-00-01  5 AV/59 ST    2407
            00-00-02  5 AV/59 ST    1687
            00-00-03  5 AV/59 ST    1272
            00-00-04  5 AV/59 ST    1352
            00-03-00  5 AV/59 ST    1834
            00-03-01  5 AV/59 ST    2753
            00-03-02  5 AV/59 ST    4192
dtype: int64
```

I need to perform an aggregation, something that looks similar to the following:

```
ipdb> busyness.groupby('STATION').sum()
*** KeyError: 'STATION'
```

How do I do this with a Series object. I'm used to dealing with DataFrames. Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2):

Since the MultiIndex levels have names, you can specify the level by name in the call to `groupby`:

```
busyness.groupby(level='STATION').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we have a multi-level index we need to call `reset_index` when constructing the `DataFrame`, as follows:

```
ipdb> import pandas as pd
ipdb> df = pd.DataFrame(busyness).reset_index()
ipdb> summed = df.groupby('STATION').sum()
ipdb> summed.head()
                   0
STATION
1 AV           48949
103 ST         51262
103 ST-CORONA  32165
104 ST          5612
110 ST         21252
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by 4. level of `Multiindex` (`python` start from `0`, so `level=3`):

```
summed = df.groupby(level=3).sum()
```